# when will be the Item Saved(Rules) event fire in sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore

I am working with sitecore rules and created a rule with predefined conditions in Item Saved.I don't know how this rule work and when this Item saved event fire.Please can anyone explain how this rule work in the Item saved event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  extend the `OnItemSaved` handler to do certain actions on the save event of the Item, such as validate the values, run a rule or populate other fields.

You need to define your rule in a custom class to perform the logic, which sounds like what you have already done.

The final step is to add your handler at the end of `<event name="item:saved">` in the `<events>` of your web.config file. Example below;

```
<event name="item:saved">
...
<!-- add the namespace name and dll  -->
<handler type="MyNamespace, MyAssemblyName" method="MyMethod"/>
</event>
```

Comment: thank you,but i am using predefined conditions in rule.I didn't define my rule in a custom class.my rule is like this                                                                                                            " where the current domain name compares to Emailcampaign
or where user profile includes valid email address
send Newsletter Message 10T023615 e-mail"

Comment: You might need to create a custom class depending on what are you trying to do when those conditions are met?

Comment: can u please help me to get references for item saved,rules,actions,scripts and conditions

Comment: I can if you can be specific what you need and what you are trying to achieve. If its a big question you it might be worth creating a separate question and answer it there

Comment: FYI, `item:saved` already contains a handler `Sitecore.Rules.ItemEventHandler` which executes all rules specified in `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Item Saved` so no need to create an additional handler :)